# Edit and Delete on mouseover of jQuery Datatable

Tags: jquery, css, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I am trying to show edit and delete buttons on mouse over of a tr in jQuery Datatable. In the process, I am almost done, but I have defined 3rd column to contain edit and delete buttons.

Below is the html and jQuery code

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
         <td>System Architect</td>
         <td></td>
         <!-- <td>Extra td</td> -->
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Garrett Winters</td>
         <td>Accountant</td>
         <td></td>
         <!-- <td>Tokyo</td> -->
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Ashton Cox</td>
         <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
         <td></td>
         <!-- <td>San Francisco</td> -->
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
         <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
         <td></td>
         <!-- <td>Edinburgh</td> -->
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery/js code

```
var trIndex = null;
 $("#example tr td").mouseenter(function() {
     trIndex = $(this).parent();
     $(trIndex).find("td:last-child").html('<a href="">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="">Delete</a>');
 });

 // remove button on tr mouseleave

 $("#example tr td").mouseleave(function() {
     $(trIndex).find('td:last-child').html("&nbsp;");
 });
```

Below screenshot represents my output.
[image]

It looks like the edit and delete operations are for the second column td. I would like to make it like the below example, which doesn't show up column for edit and delete, moreover these looks like they are outside table
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by extra column? I read two times and I feel you need to give us some additional details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing the edit/delete button outside table would be a problem. Because the mouseenter/mouseleave methods are for the table, if the mouse is over edit/delete button, it would be considered as mouseleave for the table and the buttons would never be visible at all.

Instead have a column for the edit/delete button as well and style it so that it looks as if it is outside the table.

You can define how the last column should look like by `columnDefs` option. Something like this maybe

```
var myTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{ "targets": [2], "orderable": false, width: '20%', "sClass": 'options' }]
});
```

The above piece of code will set width, remove sorting icon over the thead and add a class `options` for the last column.

You need some css to make it look as if it is outside the table as well. The below should do it

```
#example{
    border-bottom: none;
}
#example tr:last-child td:not(.options){ /* <---- options will be the class for last column */
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
#example .options{
    background: white;
    border: none;
}
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/189Lp6u6/7/**